# How to make Cucumber running in Spring, Kotlin and JUnit5 with different feature files?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, cucumber, junit5

**Context:** I have tried different configurations, and while there are many materials around Kotlin, Spring, JUnit5, and Cucumber, no good resources describe my use case. I have checked Cucumber's official docs, articles, and Stack Overflow. As the project I am experimenting with can be considered a legacy, there is no value in rewriting Cucumber tests on Kotest and alternative solutions.

**Previous solution & shortcuts**

```java
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@Cucumber
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [ZauiToTripletexApplication::class],
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT
)
@DirtiesContext
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application-dev.properties"])
class FeatureTest {
  // There is some test code with steps implementations
}
```

Maven dependencies (simplified)

```xml
      <cucumber.version>7.1.0</cucumber.version>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!--Work around. Surefire does not use JUnit's Test Engine discovery functionality -->
                        <id>CLI-test</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Running JUnit Platform CLI"/>
                                <java classname="org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher"
                                      fork="true"
                                      failonerror="true"
                                      newenvironment="true"
                                      maxmemory="1024m"
                                      classpathref="maven.test.classpath">
                                    <arg value="--include-engine"/>
                                    <arg value="cucumber"/>
                                    <arg value="--scan-classpath"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
                                </java>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The solution works alright, except it allows only a single cucumber feature file.

**Issue:**

- I need to have several different feature files and implementations to bring SpringBoot context up and integration test my code.
- In the meantime, while running single feature file, I don't want any of others to be invoked.

My current approach was based on the docs and materials I found.

```java
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@Cucumber
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [ZauiToTripletexApplication::class],
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT
)
@CucumberOptions(features = ["src/test/resources/cucumber/features"])
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application-dev.properties"])
@DirtiesContext
class SpringIntegrationGlueTest {

}
```

```java
class FeatureTest: SpringIntegrationGlueTest() {

}
```

> ERROR: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: No qualifying bean of type 'cucumber.features.SpringIntegrationGlueTest' available: expected single matching bean but found 2

On the latest error I stuck and cannot progress any further. How to make Cucumber running in Spring, Kotlin and JUnit 5 with different feature files?

Comment: Don't extend `SpringIntegrationGlueTest`.